# Adding Missing Dates From SQL Query

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to add missing dates to my query so that my results look like this:

```
10/22/2018 15
10/21/2018 0
10/20/2018 14
```

Rather than this:

```
10/22/2018 15
10/20/2018 14
```

I want the past 300 days listed, even if the output value is 0.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT TOP (300)
    CAST(createddate as DATE),
    count(DISTINCT ID)
FROM table
GROUP BY CAST(createddate as DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(createddate as DATE) DESC
```

Comment: If you got a calendar table, it's a simple Left Join to it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, please.

Comment: I am using a MS SQL database. There is no calendar table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the data:

```
WITH dates as (
      SELECT MAX(CAST(createddate as date)) as dte, 1 as lev
      FROM table
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, dte), lev + 1
      FROM dates
      WHERE lev < 300
     )
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.ID)
FROM dates d LEFT JOIN
     table t
     ON d.dte = CAST(t.createddate as DATE)
GROUP BY d.dte
ORDER BY d.dte DESC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: """Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [208] [S0002]: Invalid object name 'CTE'."""